# Why did libllvm4.0 require the autoremove command?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center

When I ran apt to install a package not listed in the Software Center, I got a warning message that libllvm4.0 was still present on my system but not needed, and advising me to use autoremove on the command line to remove it. I tried to find information on this package, and all I got was that it's some kind of C compiler library. I have g++ and various tools installed, but I'm not sure whether that installattion added this library to my system or it's left over from the (recent) operating system install or subsequent Software Updates.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3, installed from an official .iso file I downloaded last night and burned to a USB drive using Rufus from within a Win 10 OS. Rufus downloaded some isolinux-related files to complete the burning of the iso to the USB drive, but I don't know whether that inadvertently added this library to my install. I no longer have access to the Rufus downloads folder as I overwrote Windows during the install.

Comment: If you really want to know, then please edit your question to include your entire `/var/log/apt/history.log`. Or you can simply look through that file to determine when any particular package was (recently) added and why.

Answer (score 0):

You can hardily remove libllvm4.0 from the system. g++ does not require it unless you use clang++. I assume the library was sometime installed as a dependency and is not more needed after system updates or some removed program.

Comment: I'll remove it and then keep an eye for anything that looks like undefined behavior by my applications or the OS. If anything comes up, I'll post it here. If you don't hear from me again in this thread, all can assume that everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Rufus downloaded some isolinux-related files to complete the burning of the iso to the USB drive, but I don't know whether that inadvertently added this library to my install.

Rufus developer here. I can tell you with certainty that none of the isolinux/syslinux files that Rufus downloads ever end up being transferred onto the system you are installing (and they are not Linux libraries to start with!). They are only being downloaded so that isolinux/syslinux can boot the USB. Otherwise you would get an error during early boot, long before you get the ability to install anything.

The installers themselves don't know and don't care one bit about these downloaded files, and since they reside **outside** of the location where content gets copied from, I can assert with 100% certainty that your `libllvm4.0`, or whatever other library you think may have been inadvertently installed, does not come from using Rufus.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I was just casting a wide net to see what might be up, but I didn't really think Rufus was responsible.